# Is const keyword still better to have in Flutter (Dart 2) for performance?

Tags: flutter

I have read many articles and Stack Overflow questions/answers for `const` discussion.

People say if you create a const instance, that instance will be only created once. If you later try to create the same instance, the old one will be returned and no new memory allocation is required. This sounds better in performance. For example:

```dart
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0)),
    Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0)),
   ]
)
```

The above code just shows the idea. The `const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0))` doesn't have to be inside the same widget class.

Now, when I read the [official Dart 2 announcement](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6), it has an opposite example. I just copy the code block from that article here:

```dart
// Before Dart 2
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    height: 56.0,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
    child: new Row(
      ...
    ),
  );
}

// After Dart 2
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
  Container(
    height: 56.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
    child: Row(
      ...
    ),
  );
```

Thus, should I still add `const` keyword or not in Dart 2?

At the beginning, I am removing all my const keywords. But when I read people suggest to add const keywords for performance, I am adding const keywords back. But today, when I read this article by accident, I am totally confused. Will the const auto imply in Dart 2 Flutter engine for such case? OR will this matter in Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the const auto imply in Dart 2 flutter engine

No. Dart 2 does not imply `const` keyword. It removes the redundant ones.

```
Foo()
```

and

```
const Foo()
```

are *not* equivalent.

On the other hand:

```
const Foo(Bar())
```

and

```
const Foo(const Bar())
```

are indeed equivalent.

So yes, the `const` keyword is still somehow required for performance optimization.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. but it doesn't answer my real question. Should I add the const keyword or not in flutter? The announcement shows that I should remove it. Does it matter in performance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you should. In fact, you should enable `prefer_const_constructor` lint option on your `analysis_options.yaml`.

Comment: I thought I had `analysis_options.yaml`, but when I check the root, flutter create does not create it by default.... Can you please show me what a recommended `analysis_options.yaml` file should look like for flutter (an example file)?  and if you think I should add const in flutter, can you please update the answer too? I can then mark it as the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Update: I found this file https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml. So no need to show me an example now. Just please update the answer to have the suggestion of using const in flutter (dart 2). Then I can mark it as the final answer. Thanks a lot.